# group by rows with duplicated pairs, if true in any row - true in result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table:

```
source   | target | appear1 | appear2 
   1     |   a    |  true   | false  
   1     |   a    |  false  | true   
   2     |   j    |  false  | false   
   3     |   p    |  false  | false  
   4     |   w    |  true   | false   
   4     |   w    |  false  | false
```

I need to output every pair of source-target only once and if any of appear cell has true value, new row must has true in this column

For this table I must get this output:

```
source   | target | appear1 | appear2 
   1     |   a    |  true   | true   
   2     |   j    |  false  | false   
   3     |   p    |  false  | false  
   4     |   w    |  true   | false
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a boolean aggregate for that:

```
select source, 
       target, 
       bool_or(appear1) as appear1,
       bool_or(appear2) as appear2
from the_table
group by source, target
order by source, target;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/TOO42469